# Non parametric test for relation/ association of variable

Tags: scipy, statistics, kruskals-algorithm

What could be an appropriate test for checking whether there exist any relationship between Net Promoter Score ( Categorical in nature with 0 meaning detractor, 1 meaning Neutral, 2 meaning Promter ) and other variable Retention ( 0 meaning did not retain,1 meaning retained) The distribution of NPS is not normal . Also in the sample comparing means would not be helpful( I think ). The two variable are derived from a single customer.

I am using scipy library in Python to run the test.

Comment: You should ask this question over at [Cross Validated (stats.stackexhange.com)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I have asked this question there .